# Querying for Objects that contains some object in a one to many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have two models

```
class User
  has_many :roles
end

class Role
   belongs_to :user
end
```

how would I query for "who has xxx-role?"
thank you,

Comment: There are many ways to do that, Pita, and you have to be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start off my making a roles query

`roles = Role.where(some_key: some_val).includes(:user)`

You tack on the `includes` here to preload the associated user records. This way, you can get the users like so:

`roles.map(&:user)` which is equivalent to `roles.map { |role| role.user }`.

It would work without the `includes` but it would be slower. This is because of the [N+1 sequel issue](https://www.sitepoint.com/silver-bullet-n1-problem/).

Comment: Thank you,I actually ended up making it a HABTM relationship and just did Role.users. but the same idea i guess

Comment: Yeah HABTM makes more sense here